# Getting errors MSVC++ warning C4183: '_Getcont': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int' from file deque

Tags: visual-c++

So I am getting this strange errors spewing out of my compiler. It says:
warning C4183: '_Getcont': missing return type; assumed to be a member function returning 'int'. I was able to remove some errors related to this one on the class I wrote myself. The problem is this error is coming from line 159 file deque. I got similar error/warning from set. I wanted to know what causes this error to occur? I didn't use deque in the first place and I don't have #include on deque anywhere on my project.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013.

Thanks.

Comment: can you post your code that throws these warnings when compiled? and if possible compiler flags used.

Comment: In fact the problem is, I could not even trace it where it comes from. How can I know the compiler flag used? As far as I know, I didn't used any.